# Generate a matrix from a given string

Tags: python, string

I need to create a matrix from a string s where m is the given number of rows and len(s)/m is the number of columns. First column must be filled with the first m chars in the string s (I.E.: 0*m+i chars for every i in range(m) ); the second column with the 1*m+i and so on.
What's the best way to do this in python?

EDIT:
this is the code I wrote by now.

```
def split_by_n( seq, n ):
"""A generator to divide a sequence into chunks of n units."""
    while seq:
        yield seq[:n]
        seq = seq[n:]

#print list(split_by_n("1234567890",2))
input=list("ZPFKYLGJPNSGNMQGFGCITLVRIWMGFBLBFDSIOAJGBGAVFVHBGLFSRPNIOFSYOBTFCGRQLWWZAAJFUPGAFZSNXLTGARUVFKOLGAIWGUUCMVSEKLIAGJGGUZFBAOILVRIZPORNXWVFRGNMEGCEUNUZSPNIUAHFRQLWALHWEQGQKDFDCCKLUZWFSITKWIKLSMUQKNJUWRTKZAHJGABKDEGEMNCVIMBFRNYXSSKYPWLWHUKKISHFAJPOOFGJBJTBXXSGTRYAJGBNRMYHOGXQBLSFEWVUCHRLEJWAQBIWFRLWSSKRKSBFRAKDFJVRGZUOCJUZEKWAPIQSBRYM")
l = list(split_by_n(input,6))

for i in range(len(l[-2])-len(l[-1])):
    l[-1].append('$')

print l
```

Comment: Example input and output is valuable. Also what code do you have already?

Comment: The best way is always trying to solve the problem by yourself and come to stack overflow if you encounter a _specific_ problem.

Comment: Your `l` seems to be what you want already. What is it you want specifically?

Comment: I'd like to have the transpose of l so I created it using zip(*l).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned from your comment that you want to make transpose of your matrix that is formed from a given string. Your code creates the matrix from a given string just fine. I have tweaked your code only slightly, and added code for making transpose.

```
def split_by_n( seq, n ):
    while seq:
        yield seq[:n]
        seq = seq[n:]


def make_matrix(string):
    col_count = 6
    matrix = list(split_by_n(string,6))
    row_count = len(matrix)

    # the last row has "less_by" fewer elements than the rest of the rows
    less_by = len(matrix[-2]) - len(matrix[-1])
    matrix[-1] += '$' * less_by

    return matrix


def make_transpose(matrix):
    col_count = len(matrix[0])
    transpose = []
    for i in range(col_count):
        transpose.append([row[i] for row in matrix])

    return transpose


string = list("ZPFKYLGJPNSGNMQGFGCITLVRIWMGFBLBFDSIOAJGBGAVFVHBGLFSRPNIOFSYOBTFCGRQLWWZAAJFUPGAFZSNXLTGARUVFKOLGAIWGUUCMVSEKLIAGJGGUZFBAOILVRIZPORNXWVFRGNMEGCEUNUZSPNIUAHFRQLWALHWEQGQKDFDCCKLUZWFSITKWIKLSMUQKNJUWRTKZAHJGABKDEGEMNCVIMBFRNYXSSKYPWLWHUKKISHFAJPOOFGJBJTBXXSGTRYAJGBNRMYHOGXQBLSFEWVUCHRLEJWAQBIWFRLWSSKRKSBFRAKDFJVRGZUOCJUZEKWAPIQSBRYM")
matrix = make_matrix(string)

transpose = make_transpose(matrix)

for e in matrix:
    print(e)

print('\nThe transpose:')
for e in transpose:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
['Z', 'P', 'F', 'K', 'Y', 'L']
['G', 'J', 'P', 'N', 'S', 'G']
['N', 'M', 'Q', 'G', 'F', 'G']
['C', 'I', 'T', 'L', 'V', 'R']
['I', 'W', 'M', 'G', 'F', 'B']
['L', 'B', 'F', 'D', 'S', 'I']
['O', 'A', 'J', 'G', 'B', 'G']
['A', 'V', 'F', 'V', 'H', 'B']
['G', 'L', 'F', 'S', 'R', 'P']
['N', 'I', 'O', 'F', 'S', 'Y']
['O', 'B', 'T', 'F', 'C', 'G']
['R', 'Q', 'L', 'W', 'W', 'Z']
['A', 'A', 'J', 'F', 'U', 'P']
['G', 'A', 'F', 'Z', 'S', 'N']
['X', 'L', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'R']
['U', 'V', 'F', 'K', 'O', 'L']
['G', 'A', 'I', 'W', 'G', 'U']
['U', 'C', 'M', 'V', 'S', 'E']
['K', 'L', 'I', 'A', 'G', 'J']
['G', 'G', 'U', 'Z', 'F', 'B']
['A', 'O', 'I', 'L', 'V', 'R']
['I', 'Z', 'P', 'O', 'R', 'N']
['X', 'W', 'V', 'F', 'R', 'G']
['N', 'M', 'E', 'G', 'C', 'E']
['U', 'N', 'U', 'Z', 'S', 'P']
['N', 'I', 'U', 'A', 'H', 'F']
['R', 'Q', 'L', 'W', 'A', 'L']
['H', 'W', 'E', 'Q', 'G', 'Q']
['K', 'D', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'C']
['K', 'L', 'U', 'Z', 'W', 'F']
['S', 'I', 'T', 'K', 'W', 'I']
['K', 'L', 'S', 'M', 'U', 'Q']
['K', 'N', 'J', 'U', 'W', 'R']
['T', 'K', 'Z', 'A', 'H', 'J']
['G', 'A', 'B', 'K', 'D', 'E']
['G', 'E', 'M', 'N', 'C', 'V']
['I', 'M', 'B', 'F', 'R', 'N']
['Y', 'X', 'S', 'S', 'K', 'Y']
['P', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'H', 'U']
['K', 'K', 'I', 'S', 'H', 'F']
['A', 'J', 'P', 'O', 'O', 'F']
['G', 'J', 'B', 'J', 'T', 'B']
['X', 'X', 'S', 'G', 'T', 'R']
['Y', 'A', 'J', 'G', 'B', 'N']
['R', 'M', 'Y', 'H', 'O', 'G']
['X', 'Q', 'B', 'L', 'S', 'F']
['E', 'W', 'V', 'U', 'C', 'H']
['R', 'L', 'E', 'J', 'W', 'A']
['Q', 'B', 'I', 'W', 'F', 'R']
['L', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'K', 'R']
['K', 'S', 'B', 'F', 'R', 'A']
['K', 'D', 'F', 'J', 'V', 'R']
['G', 'Z', 'U', 'O', 'C', 'J']
['U', 'Z', 'E', 'K', 'W', 'A']
['P', 'I', 'Q', 'S', 'B', 'R']
['Y', 'M', '$', '$', '$', '$']

The transpose:
['Z', 'G', 'N', 'C', 'I', 'L', 'O', 'A', 'G', 'N', 'O', 'R', 'A', 'G', 'X', 'U', 'G', 'U', 'K', 'G', 'A', 'I', 'X', 'N', 'U', 'N', 'R', 'H', 'K', 'K', 'S', 'K', 'K', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'I', 'Y', 'P', 'K', 'A', 'G', 'X', 'Y', 'R', 'X', 'E', 'R', 'Q', 'L', 'K', 'K', 'G', 'U', 'P', 'Y']
['P', 'J', 'M', 'I', 'W', 'B', 'A', 'V', 'L', 'I', 'B', 'Q', 'A', 'A', 'L', 'V', 'A', 'C', 'L', 'G', 'O', 'Z', 'W', 'M', 'N', 'I', 'Q', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'I', 'L', 'N', 'K', 'A', 'E', 'M', 'X', 'W', 'K', 'J', 'J', 'X', 'A', 'M', 'Q', 'W', 'L', 'B', 'W', 'S', 'D', 'Z', 'Z', 'I', 'M']
['F', 'P', 'Q', 'T', 'M', 'F', 'J', 'F', 'F', 'O', 'T', 'L', 'J', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'I', 'M', 'I', 'U', 'I', 'P', 'V', 'E', 'U', 'U', 'L', 'E', 'F', 'U', 'T', 'S', 'J', 'Z', 'B', 'M', 'B', 'S', 'L', 'I', 'P', 'B', 'S', 'J', 'Y', 'B', 'V', 'E', 'I', 'S', 'B', 'F', 'U', 'E', 'Q', '$']
['K', 'N', 'G', 'L', 'G', 'D', 'G', 'V', 'S', 'F', 'F', 'W', 'F', 'Z', 'G', 'K', 'W', 'V', 'A', 'Z', 'L', 'O', 'F', 'G', 'Z', 'A', 'W', 'Q', 'D', 'Z', 'K', 'M', 'U', 'A', 'K', 'N', 'F', 'S', 'W', 'S', 'O', 'J', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'L', 'U', 'J', 'W', 'S', 'F', 'J', 'O', 'K', 'S', '$']
['Y', 'S', 'F', 'V', 'F', 'S', 'B', 'H', 'R', 'S', 'C', 'W', 'U', 'S', 'A', 'O', 'G', 'S', 'G', 'F', 'V', 'R', 'R', 'C', 'S', 'H', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'W', 'W', 'U', 'W', 'H', 'D', 'C', 'R', 'K', 'H', 'H', 'O', 'T', 'T', 'B', 'O', 'S', 'C', 'W', 'F', 'K', 'R', 'V', 'C', 'W', 'B', '$']
['L', 'G', 'G', 'R', 'B', 'I', 'G', 'B', 'P', 'Y', 'G', 'Z', 'P', 'N', 'R', 'L', 'U', 'E', 'J', 'B', 'R', 'N', 'G', 'E', 'P', 'F', 'L', 'Q', 'C', 'F', 'I', 'Q', 'R', 'J', 'E', 'V', 'N', 'Y', 'U', 'F', 'F', 'B', 'R', 'N', 'G', 'F', 'H', 'A', 'R', 'R', 'A', 'R', 'J', 'A', 'R', '$']
```